# Showing loading indicator only on initial load in graphql Query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have graphql Query as follows:

```
<Query query={GET_COMPANY_ADDRESSES} variables={{companyId: session.company.id}} notifyOnNetworkStatusChange={true} fetchPolicy={'cache-and-network'}>
    {({loading, error, refetch, data}) => {
        if (loading) return <LoadingIndicator/>;
        if (error) return <ErrorIndicator description={error.message}/>;

        const address = data.companyAddresses[1];

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <CollapsiblePanel title="Add slot">
                    <SlotForm address={address} toggleSlotForm={this.toggleSlotForm.bind(this)} refetch={refetch}/>
                </CollapsiblePanel>

            </React.Fragment>

        )
    }}
</Query>
```

I show there an `loading indicator` on initial load. It works fine. But I have form inside `<SlotForm />` component where I can add record to the database. The submit function of the form as follows:

```
handleSaveSlot({address}, data) {
        const slot = {
            ...data,
            address: address.id
        };

        return client.mutate({
            variables: {input: slot},
            mutation: ADD_NEW_SLOT,
        })
            .then(result => {
                if (result.data.createSlot.ok) {

                    this.props.refetch();
                    this.setState({hasError: false, errorMessage: "", saved: true, slot: initialSlot()}, () => {
                        setTimeout(() => this.props.toggleSlotForm(false), 3000)
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                let error_msg = error.message.replace("GraphQL error: ", '');
                this.setState({hasError: true, saved: false, errorMessage: error_msg});
                throw(error_msg);
            });
}
```

After response in `.then` I'm refetching the data with `this.props.refetch();`. But when refetch is executed I get the loading indicator again before the data is updated on the screen.

I want to avoid that and I do not want to show `loading indicator` every time when I add a new record. I just want to show it on initial load.

Every time when I refetch the data I want to do that "in background" without showing loading indicator.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient to change your conditional like this:

```
if (loading && !data.companyAddresses) {
  return <LoadingIndicator/>;
}
```

`data.companyAddresses` will be undefined until your initial query is complete, but should be defined even when you trigger a refetch.

If possible, you should also consider using the `update` option with your `Mutation` component, rather than refetching the query. Updating your cache manually after a mutation is typically better than refetching since it's faster and reduces network load. See [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#update) for more details.